# Changing the checked attribute of a table data of input type radio

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, frontend

My html file has a table with table data of input type radio. Based on the users selection the defauted checked radio should. I have tried to change the value from a javascript file but still the default radio is still checked. The html file has the following code.

```
 <tr>
          <td width="1%"><input type="radio" name="cell-recon-search-for-match-mode" checked="true" bind="radioSimilar" id="$cell-recon-search-match-similar" /></td>
          <td><label for="$cell-recon-search-match-similar" bind="or_views_matchOther"></label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="1%"><input type="radio" name="cell-recon-search-for-match-mode" bind="radioOne" id="$cell-recon-search-match-one" /></td>
          <td><label for="$cell-recon-search-match-one" bind="or_views_matchThis"></label></td>
        </tr>
```

From the javascript file am trying to update checked radio using the below code.

```
var frame = $(DOM.loadHTML("core", "scripts/views/data-table/cell-recon-search-for-match.html"));
  var elmts = DOM.bind(frame);

(function(){
//$("#cell-recon-search-match-similar").prop("checked", false);....1
elmts.radioSimilar[0].setAttribute(checked, "false");....2
});

DialogSystem.showDialog(frame);
```

Both methods 1 and 2 do not achieve the desired outcome. The default radio is still checked. What is it that I could be doing wrong.

Below is the complete html file

```
<div class="dialog-frame" style="width: 450px;">
  <div class="dialog-border">
    <div class="dialog-header" bind="dialogHeader"></div>
    <div class="dialog-body" bind="dialogBody">
      <div class="grid-layout layout-tighter"><table>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2"><span bind="or_views_searchFor"></span> "<span bind="cellTextSpan"></span>"</td>
          <td><input bind="input" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="1%"><input type="radio" name="cell-recon-search-for-match-mode" checked="true" bind="radioSimilar" id="$cell-recon-search-match-similar" /></td>
          <td><label for="$cell-recon-search-match-similar" bind="or_views_matchOther"></label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="1%"><input type="radio" name="cell-recon-search-for-match-mode" bind="radioOne" id="$cell-recon-search-match-one" /></td>
          <td><label for="$cell-recon-search-match-one" bind="or_views_matchThis"></label></td>
        </tr>
      </table></div>
    </div>
    <div class="dialog-footer" bind="dialogFooter">
      <button class="button button-primary" bind="okButton"></button>
      <button class="button" bind="newButton"></button>
      <button class="button" bind="clearButton"></button>
      <button class="button" bind="cancelButton"></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try : `$("input[id='$cell-recon-search-match-similar']").prop("checked", false);`

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear that what actually you want to do. but it seems like you want to remove the default checked radio button.

One thing I have noted is that you are using the '$' sign in id and for, even with that you are using jquery also, which has a specific meaning of the '$' sign.
So please note that also.

Now if you want to remove the checked radio button then simply see the below line.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
// removed $ from the id 
$('#cell-recon-search-match-similar').attr('checked', false);
 });
```

Before this note that I have removed '$' from the id. because I don't see this as a good way to define id.

Comment: An exception is generated Uncaught TypeError: $(...).atrr is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (project-bundle.js:44615:39)
    at fire (project-bundle.js:3234:31)

Comment: okay have you added Jquey CDN.
Please add the following below your closing head tag. </head> Please not that do not add this at the end of the body.
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

we have to load jquey when the page is loaded so we have to add it at the head instead of body whenever we are using jquery.

Comment: @walton look closely to the error message --  `$(...).atrr`  it's `attr` not `atrr`  .

Comment: @Brijal Kansara I will do that and keep you posted

Comment: @Brijal Kansara I have edited the post to include the the contents of the htm file. There is no head and body tag. The html page is being created from the js file var frame = $(DOM.loadHTML("core", "scripts/views/data-table/cell-recon-search-for-match.html"));
  var elmts = DOM.bind(frame);

Comment: This file must be extending any html file like main.html ornindex.html. you can add jQuery cdn there. Or have you tried to include th le cdn in above html file. I am sure it will work. Add cdn within same file. Inside script tag

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the `checked` attribute of the element to false, try the checked property on the element object. Like you did in .....1. **NB**: A wrong id was provided. i.e this `cell-recon-search-match-similar` instead of `$cell-recon-search-match-similar` Example

```js
(function(){
   $("#$cell-recon-search-match-similar").prop("checked", false);
});

DialogSystem.showDialog(frame);
```

Comment: There  is a challege with this method. Its like $ is not being considered as part of the id.   Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #$cell-recon-search-match-similar
    at Function.Sizzle.error (project-bundle.js:1504:8)
    at Sizzle.tokenize (project-bundle.js:2161:11)
    at Sizzle.select (project-bundle.js:2582:20)
    at Function.Sizzle (project-bundle.js:905:9)
    at Function.jQuery.find (project-bundle.js:11304:17)